# Passing an array of characters as function arguments

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I am trying to pass a string as an argument to a function and it throws a Segmentation fault(Core Dumped) error. Could you please let me know what mistake I am making here? Here is the code:

```
replaceChars(char str[], char sChar[], char rChar)
{
int i,j;
printf("rChar is %c", rChar);
printf("sChar is %s", sChar);

for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j <= strlen(sChar); j++)
    {
     if(str[i] == sChar[j])  
     {
        str[i] = rChar;
        //printf("The New String is %c", str[i]);
     }
    }
}

printf("The New String is %s", str);
}
void main()
{
char myString[36], schar[36], rchar;

printf("Please enter a string:");

scanf("%[^\n]s", &myString);

printf("Which characters to replace?");
scanf(" %[^\n]c", &schar);
printf("With which character?");
scanf(" %[^\n]c", &rchar);

replaceChars(myString, schar, rchar);

}
```

Comment: replace `<=` with `<` in your loop

Comment: Please take the [Tour] and read [Ask]. Please [edit] your post and fix your code indentation. It's nice when an [MCVE] includes a `main` function that calls the function you are debugging.

Comment: Also, learn to use whatever debugger is available in your development environment. Buffer overruns are easily detected by stepping through your own code and watching your local variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @kerrytazi! However, after I did the above change, the str value is getting printed as null. Can you help me with this?

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]c", &rchar);` is bad

Answer (score 2):

Two issues here.

First, when you loop through `str` and `sChar`:

> I am trying to pass a string as an argument to a function and it throws a Segmentation fault(Core Dumped) error. Could you please let me know what mistake I am making here? Here is the code:

```
for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j <= strlen(sChar); j++)
    {
```

You use `<=` as your exit condition.  Array indexes start from 0, so valid indexes are from 0 to length-1.  You're going from 0 to length, so you're stepping of the end of the array.  Reading past the end of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change the conditions to use `<`:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < strlen(sChar); j++)
    {
```

The second problem is in how you're reading the values:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", &myString);
...
scanf(" %[^\n]c", &schar);
...
scanf(" %[^\n]c", &rchar);
```

The `%[]` format specifier doesn't require any characters after it, and it requires a `char *` as a parameter which points to the first element of an array of `char`.  In the first two cases, you're passing the address of an array instead of the array itself (which decays to a pointer) and you have an extra character after the `%[]` format that isn't needed.  In the third case you pass a pointer to a single `char` when a pointer to multiple characters is expected by the format.  Because you want to read a single char, you want to use the `%c` format specifier instead.

```
scanf("%35[^\n]", myString);
...
scanf(" %35[^\n]", schar);
...
scanf(" %c", &rchar);
```

Note also that the first two have a field width that limits the number of characters that are read so that you don't overrun the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please let me know what mistake I am making here?

In addition to [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635216/2410359) good answer, OP's code is unnecessarily inefficient.

Using the corrected code below, and assume the initial length of the `str, sChar` are `S,C` respectively.

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < strlen(sChar); j++) {
    if(str[i] == sChar[j]) {
      str[i] = rChar;
    }
  }
}
```

The `for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {` and with the later `str[i] = rChar;` obliges the code to find the length of `str` up to S times and each `strlen(str)` requires O(S) operations.

If `S` was a non-trivial value, say 1000, this 1000*1000 could readily affect overall performance.  A simply solution is to calculate the length once or look for the *null character* instead.

```
// for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
S = strlen(str);
for(i = 0; i < S; i++) {
// or
for(i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
```

---

The same thing happens with the inner loop too.  Yet a smart compiler can see that `sChar` does not change and may take advantage of understanding  `strlen()` has no side effects that would cause for a different result.  With such an optimization `strlen(sChar)` may be truly called once, even if `strlen(sChar)` in inside the higher `for (i...)` loop.

Still it is easy and idiomatic to just test for the *null character*.

```
    // for(j = 0; j < strlen(sChar); j++)
    // better as
    for(j = 0; sChar[j]; j++)
```

---

Yet why does this not apply to the `for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)` loop?

Within that loop, code can modify `str[]` and so the compiler cannot make the optimization as with `for(j = 0; sChar[j]; j++)`.

This also begs the question, what should code do if the replacement character `rChar` is the *null character*?

As I see it, code could either continue, replacing with a `'\0` multiple times or simple return after this first.

```
       str[i] = rChar;
       if (rChar == '\0') return; // Possible way to handle \0
```